# zpool replace ran successfully, but still recommends zpool replace. What is it telling me?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, ubuntu-18.04, zfsonlinux, zpool

A drive failed in a raidz3 (`pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:10:0`), and I replaced it with an available spare (wwn-0x5000c500858252ef):

```
  pool: darkpool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
    repaired.
  scan: resilvered 3.16T in 137h44m with 0 errors on Mon Sep 23 16:07:06 2019
config:

    NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    darkpool                              DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz3-0                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581aafb            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b61b            ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdm                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b953            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581bdf7            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085825ec7            ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581e423            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581fd3f            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085820b93            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500858211b3            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000cca267ab0de4            ONLINE       0     0     0
        spare-13                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:10:0  FAULTED      0    69     0  too many errors
          wwn-0x5000c500858252ef          ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      wwn-0x5000c500858252ef              INUSE     currently in use
```

I thought the spare would go away after resilvering, and become a member of the pool. But the `DEGRADED` state persisted, and the spare was still `INUSE` filling in for the bad drive.

The recommendation was `replace the faulted device, or use use 'zpool clear' to mark the device as repaired.`

I completely misunderstood what `clear` meant. That's my mistake. I think I just made things worse.

```
  pool: darkpool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub in progress since Mon Sep 23 17:12:17 2019
    6.18T scanned out of 46.4T at 162M/s, 72h16m to go
    0B repaired, 13.31% done
config:

    NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    darkpool                              DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz3-0                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581aafb            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b61b            ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdm                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b953            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581bdf7            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085825ec7            ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581e423            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581fd3f            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085820b93            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500858211b3            ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000cca267ab0de4            ONLINE       0     0     0
        spare-13                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:10:0  FAULTED      0     0     0  corrupted data
          wwn-0x5000c500858252ef          ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      wwn-0x5000c500858252ef              INUSE     currently in use

errors: No known data errors
```

I've added another drive in the final open slot, `wnn-0x5000cca26788a8f8`, but what should I be replacing here?

---

Output of `lsscsi`:

```
[0:0:2:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c500858211b3                  /dev/sda 
[0:0:3:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581b953                  /dev/sdb 
[0:0:4:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c50085825ec7                  /dev/sdc 
[0:0:5:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581e423                  /dev/sdd 
[0:0:6:0]    disk    HGST     HUH721008AL5205  D384  0x5000cca26788a8f8                  /dev/sdq 
[0:0:7:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581b61b                  /dev/sde 
[0:0:8:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581aafb                  /dev/sdf 
[0:0:9:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581cc03                  /dev/sdg 
[0:0:10:0]   disk    HGST     HUH721008AL5205  D384  0x5000cca267ab0de4                  /dev/sdh 
[0:0:11:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c50085823d2b                  /dev/sdi 
[0:0:12:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581b933                  /dev/sdj 
[0:0:13:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581bdf7                  /dev/sdk 
[0:0:14:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c50085820b93                  /dev/sdl 
[0:0:15:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581b79f                  /dev/sdm 
[0:0:16:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c500858252ef                  /dev/sdn 
[0:0:17:0]   disk    SEAGATE  ST8000NM0075     PS24  0x5000c5008581fd3f                  /dev/sdo 
[0:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H330 Adp    4.27  0x61866da05f3bc2001f1c1a0d117e72cf  /dev/sdp 
[10:0:0:0]   cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GHB0N    A1C0  0x5001480000000000                  /dev/sr0
```

---

```
sudo zfs get version darkpool
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE    SOURCE
darkpool  version   5        -
```

I believe the pool was created on Ubuntu 14.04

```
History for 'darkpool':
2016-07-15.10:38:13 [txg:5] create pool version 5000; software version 5000/5; uts hippocampus 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
```

---

No, I don't know who set these names up, I prefer by-id, though it doesn't seem to matter anymore in Ubuntu 18.

Comment: What is the specific version of ZFS on your system?

Comment: Also, can you `lsscsi -w` for me?

Comment: @ewwhite sure, thanks for the command. Super useful! I had such a laborious way of figuring out the associations before.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cleared your zpool errors too early (the resilver was in progress) However, you should not have done any harm to pool health.

Let your pool resilver, then issue `zpool clear darkpool` and finally do `zpool scrub darkpool`. This should be enough to have a clean pool.

Comment: I think I have to OFFLINE `pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:10:0` right? The resilver and scrub already finished.